# How is it best to upgrade to python 3 on a Mac with Catalina OS?

Tags: python, macos, macos-catalina

I have recently done a fresh install of Mac OS Catalina on my iMac and I noticed that it already has python 3.7.3 and the latest pip3 installed. I would like to upgrade to 3.8. How can this be done? Can I upgrade the python 3 installation already on Catalina somehow or is it best to install another instance of python 3 with Homebrew? If the latter, how do I point python3 and pip3 to 3.8 and would that mess up the OS in anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use Anaconda to avoid any impact to the system Python and it comes with a lot of packages many people need for various purposes. First, install Anaconda 3.7 from the [website](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section). The installer says Python 3.7 for [a reason](https://www.anaconda.com/anaconda-individual-edition-2020-02/), because some major packages like `tensorflow` does not support Python 3.8 yet, however, it still support Python 3.8 environment well. Once Anaconda is installed, open a new terminal and run the following command.

```
$ conda create -n py38 anaconda=2020.02 python=3.8
```

Once it's done, you can run this to go into Python 3.8 environment.

```
$ conda activate py38
```

Hope that helps!